# What is the best way to access data within nested structs, all of which are Optional using MongoDB's Rust driver?

Tags: mongodb, rust, struct, option-type

I have a set of structs that are nested, and all the data is optional.  Structs are similar to the following (for  simplicity I've removed some of the Optionals):

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Device {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    pub id: Option<bson::oid::ObjectId>,
    pub system: Option<System>,
}
```

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct System {
    pub id: Option<u32>,
    pub mac: Option<String>,
}
```

When I query the db, I get the data:

```
Ok(Some(Device { id: Some(ObjectId("...")),  system: Some(System { id: Some(123), mac: Some("1234") })}))
```

I am trying to access the id value within the System struct.  I can access it easily with a few nested match statements, but I was wondering if there is an easier solution.  I've been looking at unwrap_or, unwrap_or_else, but I haven't been able to get the syntax correct.  Ideally returning a 0 will suffice, as that value is used to denote an error within the application structure.  The nested match statements work fine - it is just a bit verbose.

Alternatively I could also just use the aggregation pipeline to get the value.  I'm just curious about alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: why put Option on `System` if all it's inner field are also Option ?

Comment: @stargateur Data in this struct is dynamically built (and updated) from telemetry data received from the device.  Its possible that the System might not be present the first time the struct is created in the database.  I didn't provide the full description of all the structs in the question to keep it concise.

Comment: didn't change a thing to my remark. The only thing that would fix my comment would be to put a not Option field in System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `and_then` to apply a function to the contained `Ok` value, and leave `None`s unchanged. For example, imagine the following structure:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: Option<Bar>
}

struct Bar {
    baz: Option<Baz>
}

struct Baz {
    value: Option<i32>
}
```

You can then query the nested data like:

```rust
fn read_value(foo: Foo) -> Option<i32> {
    foo.bar
        .and_then(|bar| bar.baz) 
        .and_then(|baz| baz.value)
}
```

If any of the `Option`'s are `None`, the whole expression will be `None`, otherwise it will be the contained `Some(value)`